# what does fit method do when loading pretrained model (e.g. from onnx file)

Tags: ml.net

Could I get rid of the pipeline.Fit(trainingData) method if I load a fully trained model (e.g. from an onnx file)?

What does the fit method do anyway? I read in some sources the method would performing a training step, in other sources I read it fits the pipeline (whatever that should mean). I also read that the fit method just performs the steps defined in the pipeline before.

But do I need this steps from the pipeline if I load a fully trained model?
When I load a model from a .zip file I don`t need the fit method.

To clarify my question I added some code...
(The code doesn`t run without errors... I suggest some problems with the naming of some input and output columns... but thats not the part of the question. ;) )
I want to call the CreatePredictionEngine without the .fit method.
(As said before it would be possible with saved .zip models)

Thanks for clarification in advance. ;)

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.LoadImages(outputColumnName: "image", imageFolder: "", inputColumnName: nameof(ImageData.ImagePath))
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(outputColumnName: "image", imageWidth: ImageNetSettings.imageWidth, imageHeight: ImageNetSettings.imageHeight, inputColumnName: "image"))
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "inception_v3_input", inputColumnName: "image"))
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(modelFile: modelLocation, outputColumnNames: new[] { TinyYoloModelSettings.ModelOutput }, inputColumnNames: new[] { TinyYoloModelSettings.ModelInput }))
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "LabelKey", inputColumnName: "Label"))
                            .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.LbfgsMaximumEntropy(labelColumnName: "LabelKey", featureColumnName: TinyYoloModelSettings.ModelOutput))
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabelValue", "PredictedLabel"))
                            .AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext);


IDataView trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<ImageData>(path: _trainTagsTsv, hasHeader: false);

ITransformer model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData);


var imageData = new ImageData()
{
   ImagePath = _url
};

var predictor = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ImageData, ImagePrediction>(model);
var prediction = predictor.Predict(imageData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend you to read this document on [high-level concepts](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/MlNetHighLevelConcepts.md) of ML.NET. As a fellow developer, this may speak to you better than the derived docs and recipes :)

That doc is unfortunately a little bit outdated: I wrote it before we finalized the API on prediction engines, so the code in 'prediction function' will not compile. The rest of the document appears to still hold.

In ML.NET API design, we followed the set of [Spark naming conventions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/ml-guide.html). Unfortunately for us, sklearn uses the same names with [completely different semantics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html). So, ML.NET does what Spark does, not what sklearn does.

---

In short, the 'pipeline' is an *Estimator*. Estimators have only one operation: `Fit`, which takes data and produces a *Transformer*.

*Transformers*, on the other hand, take data and produce data. The ZIP file that you save the model in contains the transformer.

`PredictionEngine` is constructed out of a *Transformer*.

Typically, an *Estimator* is a 'pipeline' or 'chain' of trainable and non-trainable operators, that include a ML algorithm. However, this is not a requirement: you can build a pipeline out of only non-trainable operators (such as loading an ONNX model from a file). It will still be an *Estimator* (and therefore you have to call `Fit` to get the *Transformer*, even though in this case `Fit` will be a no-op).

The `MLContext`'s `Append` methods, by design, only create *Estimators*. Call it the price of strong typing, but `Fit` is a requirement.

---

In this explanation I deliberately didn't use the term 'model': unfortunately, it has become so loaded that it's hard to tell whether 'model' refers to 'the ML algorithm', or 'a mutable object that can train itself', or 'the result of such training'.